# How to change screen resolution and whenever process killed resolution back to normal?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create an environments for the user when he/she open my game screen changes to specified resolution and whenever the game process is being killed screen resolution back itself to normal.
And my game is an console application.

I did try changing resolution by these methods

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int EnumDisplaySettings (string deviceName, int modeNum, ref DEVMODE1 devMode );         
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int ChangeDisplaySettings(ref DEVMODE1 devMode, int flags);
```

But when the game closed screen resolution remains the same.